# 'Unregistered' is offset on the user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, users

When viewing unregistered users ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491112/daniel), but he's probably about to get destroyed), the 'unregistered' indicator is offset wrong:

[image: Unregistered user]

Answer (score 30):

The offset is actually the same (see it on [another site](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/7073/julia) - and yes, it took me a while to find an unregistered user on another site), but the new design decreased the font size of the username and moved the "less info" up a little bit, which makes it appear slightly off.

This can be remedied (i.e. returned in appearance to the old design) by setting the `line-height` to ~25px like this (right now it's at 40px for all sites):

[image: 25px line height]

Alternatively (and better-looking, in my opinion), you can just remove the property entirely, leaving it in line with the "less info" and the username:

[image: No line height]

Either way is better than the current design, though.